# AJAX no se ejecuta con elemento <a> con href indicado

Tags: php, javascript

Buenas,

Estoy usando un pequeño script para que se me actualice la base de datos cuando hago click en un enlace. Ese enlace tiene un evento `onclick`. Al principio para ver los valores que me estaba dando en la consola, no tenía puesto ningún enlace. Una vez visto que funcionaba, al poner el enlace, algo pasa, puesto que no se modifica la base de datos.

El código HTML referente al enlace:

```
echo "<a rel='nofollow' onclick='leido(" . $id_mencion . ")' href='foro.php?foro=" . $mencion['foro'] . "&subforo=" . $mencion['subforo'] . "&hilo=" . str_replace(" ", "%",$informacion_hilo[0]['asunto']) . "&ID=" . $id_hilo . "&pagina=" . $mencion['pagina_hilo'] . "'><strong>" . $informacion_hilo[0]['asunto'] . "</strong></a>";
```

El Script:

```
<script>
function leido(respuesta_id) {
 var id_respuesta = respuesta_id;
 console.log(id_respuesta);

    $.ajax ({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'process_leido.php',
      data: { "id_respuesta":id_respuesta }
    });

};
</script>
```

También pongo el código de process_leido.php:

```
<?php

session_start();

require 'admin/config.php';

try {
   $conexion = new PDO($bd_config['dbname'], $bd_config['usuario'], $bd_config['password'] );
} catch (Exception $e) {
   echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}

$id = isset($_POST['id_respuesta'])? $_POST['id_respuesta'] : 0;

$statement = $conexion->prepare("UPDATE menciones SET leido = 1 WHERE id = :id");
$statement->execute(array(":id" => $id));


?>
```

Sin embargo, si modifico el enlace a y le quito el contenido del parámetro `href` sí que funciona:

```
echo "<a rel='nofollow' onclick='leido(" . $id_mencion . ")' href='#'><strong>" . $informacion_hilo[0]['asunto'] . "</strong></a>";
```

He mirado y remirado y no veo dónde está el error. De hecho, el enlace es correcto.

EDITO:

Este es el HTML que me genera PHP:

```
<div class="info_hilo">
    <a rel="nofollow" onclick="leido(16)" href="foro.php?foro=Xbox%One&subforo=General&hilo=Primer%trailer%oficial%de%Destiny%2&ID=45&pagina=0"><strong>Primer trailer oficial de Destiny 2</strong></a>                                       
    <p class="creador">GoitxoCv</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Puedes por favor poner en HTML renderizado como te deja en php tu codigo: *echo "<a rel='nofollow' onclick='leido(" . $id_mencion . ")' href='#'><strong>" . $informacion_hilo[0]['asunto'] . "</strong></a>";* Quiero ver que valor de deja en el : *$id_mencion*

Comment: Dentro de la función "leido" hacer la asignación del valor que tienes en el href; cuando el Ajax  concluya haces "window.location.href=URLconParametros"; claro agrega a la función "leido" un parámetro más donde pases lo que actualmente tiene para href.

Comment: @AlfonsoCarrasco Creo que te refieres a esto aunque no estoy muy seguro, el resultado que me da por ejemplo es `<a rel="nofollow" onclick="leido(16)" href="#"><strong>Primer trailer oficial de Destiny 2</strong></a>`. `$id_mencion` no es más que un identificador.

Comment: @RobertoLeónOramas te refieres a pasar todos los valores de los parámetros de la URL por ajax para hacer la redirección en el fichero `process_leido.php`? Si es así lo he pensado, pero entiendo que no me funciona por algún error...no le veo sentido que me esté fallando. No sé si es porque al redireccionar la información se pierde o qué pasa.

Comment: Te está pidiendo que coloques el HTML que te genera PHP para dicho enlace, **pero con la URL que generas**, no la de `#`. Es posible que haya un error sintáctico en el HTML generado.

Comment: @GustavoGarcía Acabo de editar la pregunta y he puesto el HTML que genera en la parte de abajo.

Comment: ¿Llega la petición a PHP o simplemente no se ejecuta el código JS?

Comment: @GustavoGarcía No se ejecuta el código JS, al redirigirse ni siquiera puedo ver la información de la consola.

Comment: Entonces haz un fix rápido, elimina el `href` y en su lugar, pasa como segundo parámetro a `leido` la URL que generas con PHP. Por último, cuando la petición AJAX sea resuelta, redireccionas a la URL por medio de `window.location = url`. De esta manera tienes más control si la petición AJAX devuelve algún error, en lugar de redireccionar asumiendo que todo salió perfecto, el usuario puede saber que ha pasado algo malo.

Comment: Yo quisiera saber una cosa: ¿Qué hace una etiqueta `<strong>` dentro de una etiqueta `<a>`?  Me refiero a esto: `echo "<a rel='nofollow' onclick='leido(" . $id_mencion . ")' href='foro.php?foro=" . $mencion['foro'] . "&subforo=" . $mencion['subforo'] . "&hilo=" . str_replace(" ", "%",$informacion_hilo[0]['asunto']) . "&ID=" . $id_hilo . "&pagina=" . $mencion['pagina_hilo'] . "'><strong>" . $informacion_hilo[0]['asunto'] . "</strong></a>";` ¿Acaso no puede ser eso **problemático**, además de que es incorrecto y encima no sirve? Ver:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8489080/stronga-or-astrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El comportamiento de un `anchor (a)` en un documento HTML es redirigir el navegador al recurso que apunte.
Como estás apuntando a una dirección, el navegador *va a redirigirse* obedeciendo dicho `a`.

Para evitar esto, usa [`preventDefault` de jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/):

Html:

```
echo "<a rel='nofollow' onclick='leido(event, \"" . $id_mencion . "\")'...>"
```

JS:

```
leido = function(e, respuesta_id){
    e.preventDefault();
    ...
}
```

---

**EDIT**

Para redirigir el navegador solo tienes que incluir un `location.href` cuando el ajax haya devuelto un resultado exitoso:

```
$.ajax ({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'process_leido.php',
    data: { "id_respuesta":id_respuesta },
    // A partir de aquí
    success: function(data){
        location.href = '<? echo "foro.php?foro=" . $mencion['foro'] . "&subforo=" . $mencion['subforo'] . "&hilo=" . str_replace(" ", "%",$informacion_hilo[0]['asunto']) . "&ID=" . $id_hilo . "&pagina=" . $mencion['pagina_hilo']" ?>';
    },
    error: function(err){
        console.log(err); //  O cualquier cause que quieras dar
                          //   en caso de que el AJAX fracase
    }
});
```

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario. El problema es que quiero que me lleve a la URL en cuestión, pero que modifique con AJAX también la base de datos.

Comment: Actualicé mi respuesta para orientarte en ello.

Comment: ¡Solucionado! ¡Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Cuando necesito pasar parámetros por la URL, para manipularlo en PHP, y enviar una respuesta, intenta manipular este código, lo importante es mandar los parámetros correctos por la URL ya luego desde el servidor lograras lo que sea con los valores que te pasa.

```html
<?php
       echo "<a href='leido.php' id='leido'></a>"
       ?>
        <script>
        $("#leido").click(
                function(event){
                    var cURL = $(this).attr('href')+"?foro=<?php echo $mencion['foro'] ?>"+"&subforo=<?php echo $mencion["subforto"] ?>"+"&hilo=<?php echo str_replace(" ", "%", $informacion_hilo[0]["asunto"]) ?>"+"&ID=<?php echo $id_hilo ?>"+"&pagina=<?php echo $mencion["pagina_hilo"] ?>";                   
                    $.ajax({
                        url:'process_leido.php'+''+cURL+'',
                        type:"GET",
                        data: cURL,
                        cache: false,
                        success: function(data){
                            //CODE HERE
                        },
                        error: function(data){
                            console.log(data);
                        }
                    });
                    return false;
                });
        </script>
```

Puedes debugear con la función y el parametro (data) para ver que te responde el servidor, este codigo siempre me funciona, no se como estan construidas tus variables, pero la clave tambien es mandar los parametros con un echo, de lo contrario no resultara.

PD: Estoy usando Jquery

Comment: Quizas no te marca un error, pero no estas mandando los parametros de manera correcta, y no te lanza ningun catch la base de datos porque la sentencia este correcta